# Why can multiple consumers access a *single* v4l2-loopback stream from a webcam

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera, v4l, v4l2loopback

I recently needed a single webcam to be shared simultaneously by 3 applications (a web browser, a videoconferencing app, and ffmpeg to save the stream).

It's not possible to simply share the /dev/video* stream because as soon as one application is using it, the others cannot, and anything else will get a "device or resource busy" or equivalent.

So I turned to v4l2-loopback with the intention of mirroring the webcam to 3 loopbacks.

Using 3 loopbacks does work as expected, but what has really surprised me is it turns out I don't actually *need* 3 loopbacks, but only 1.

If I create a single loopback and feed it with ffmpeg, then the **single mirrored loopback** can be used by **all 3 applications at the same time**, with no "device or resource busy" issue.

So this is even better than I planned, and there is no practical problem I need help with.

But my question is, how is this possible with the loopback? And why not using the original source directly?

Example command to create the single loopback:

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=30 exclusive_caps=1 card_label="loopback cam"`

Example command using ffmpeg to mirror /dev/video5 to the loopback (/dev/video30). This will default to raw, but recent builds of ffmpeg can use an alternative stream like MJPEG, the behaviour is the same regardless:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video5 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video30`

After doing this, try to access /dev/video30 with multiple applications, here are some examples:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video30 -codec libx264 recordstream.mp4
ffplay -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video30
```

System info in case it's relevant:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic
- package: v4l2loopback-dkms 0.12.3-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's by design. First, let it be said that multiple processes can open the /dev/video0 device, but only one of them will be able to issue certain *controls* (ioctl()) until streaming starts.

Those V4L2 *controls* define things like bitrate. After you start streaming, the kernel will not let you change them and returns `EBUSY` (Device or resource busy) if you try.  See [this note](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.14/source/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ctrls.c#L3439) in the kernel source. That effectively blocks other consumers, since you should set those before you start streaming.

What does v4l2loopback do differently? It adds logic and data structures for [multiple openers](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/d3f15e3ce3388d5b4a99c2240aac3c06bc39dda8/v4l2loopback.c#L1828) and by default will [not try to apply new controls](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/d3f15e3ce3388d5b4a99c2240aac3c06bc39dda8/v4l2loopback.c#L1196) by provinding its own setter.

Note that v4l2loopback needs to have multiple openers, [at least two to be useful](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/v4l2loopback.c#L191). One reader and one writer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is very clear.
A v4l2loopback contributor [has also responded](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/310#issuecomment-633419106) and noted that this behaviour could be removed in the future.

Comment: thanks for sharing that @justyn, it's great to also have an answer from the horse's mouth.